# How do I check for an empty object in VB?

Tags: vb.net, object, is-empty, isnullorempty

How do I check for an empty object in VB?
Specifically, a function may sometimes return the following:

```
Return {}
```

How I check whether `{}` is returned as compared to an object with properties and data? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing like an _"empty object"_ in VB.NET. There are empty arrays though

Comment: What is the return type of the function? There may be a useful difference between returning an empty array and returning Nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just returns an empty array. The array will depend on the return type of the function or it will be Object(). Just check if .Length is equal to 0.

I assume you have Option Strict Off, you should turn it on :)

Comment: _"That just returns an empty array"_ -> "That just returns an empty `Object()`"

Comment: Can I still check that .Length is 0 for an empty object as well?

Comment: @HartleySan The word "empty" object is a bit confusing. If you talk about null object then you could check for IsNot Nothing before looking at .Length

Comment: So if `{}` might be returned, then I should check for `IsNot Nothing` than `.Length` is `0`?

Comment: @HartleySan {} does not return Nothing, it returns an empty array (a valid array with no element inside). If the function does not return Nothing then looking at .Length is enough.

Comment: As stated before, Option Strict On.

Answer (score 0):

For me `Dim cellValue = DataRow.Item("SomeName")` sets `cellValue` to `{}`
So to check it:

```
If (VarType(cellValue) = vbNull) Then
    ...
End If
```